# Chuwi hi8 stuck on Intel Inside logo

Tags: android, reset

I hope that I am at the right place to ask this question.

Yesterday, when I tried to install xposed framework, everything works well until reboot. It's stuck on intel inside logo now. To not be confused, it's trying to start android, and sometimes it's started, but Google Maps shown first (I really don't know why), and I get the forced close, and back to Intel logo again, trying to start android.
Windows part is working well, and I can switch to windows at any time by going to OS chooser when I'm turning on my tablet (by pressing power button + volume down).

Tablet have some options (holding power + volume up), showing some advanced options, something like cwm at android phones, but I wasn't looking at that so much (every time I started that, it was by mistake, holding volume up instead volume down to bring OS switcher). Now, I can't open that menu, it says entering DnX, waiting for fastboot command, and skipping that part for about 5 minutes.

What can I do to hardreset the android part? I don’t have standard menu like on (only) android tablets and phones. The tablet is very good, but this is bothering me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by myself. When every option failed, I connected tablet to computer, started adb and run `adb reboot recovery` which opened recovery menu. Wiping data was success and android started from scratch.